# Why doesn't Chromecast respect fractional playbackRate values on video elements?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

Using the debugger on the sample cast app I try to set a fractional playback value:

```
document.getElementById("vid").playbackRate = 0.5;
```

And the video will not change speed. If I set playbackRate to zero the video will pause. And if I set it to 1.0 it will resume. Note that on chrome desktop the video element DOES respect fractional playbackRate values.

Comment: What happens if you set the rate to 1.5? To 2.0?

Comment: Yeah more interested in the 1.5 & 2.0 use case. Would be a shame if this isn't supported.

Comment: As of 2023, using a very old Chromecast Ultra, it seems that 1.0 ~ 2.0 rates work, but sub 1.0 rates do not.

Answer (score 3):

This was disabled on the device due to the hardware limitations. For example, if one tries to play an HD movie in 3x speed, the hardware won't be able to keep up so it was disabled to avoid such issues. If there is a strong need to support rates < 1, please open a feature request and our team will review that.

Comment: Is this still the case with the latest update or are there any plans to allow it?

Comment: I tested this and it seems to work, has this been enabled again?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, for now, Chromecast doesn't support any playbackRate values besides 1 and 0, not just fractional ones. Everything else I tried (fractions and whole numbers from -1 to 3) all resulted in normal speed playback, with 0 making it pause.

Answer (score 0):

Play rate control is very useful (almost required) for finer controlling adaptive streaming where a slight slow down or speed up can help to increase or shrink the latency.

`< 1x` is perfectly fine for this purpose. In fact, probably no more than **10-15% delta** will be employed for this kind of optimzation.

In addition, this is a standard video element method. Not supporting it at all is a serious defect. Supporting it with limitation is perfectly fine.

Please consider this seriously. If there is a more formal place to place this request, please let me know.

Comment: Feature Requests for Cast SDK can be made here: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list